# Is there a way to view the text from posts on a facebook profile, in the actual HTML source code?

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a scraper using Python, Selenium and BS to crawl through various websites given a list of URL's and output the raw html source code to a CSV to be cleaned and scanned for keywords. Everything works fine on my facebook crawler except that the HTML source code doesn't actually include the text from the various posts that have been rendered on the page. Is there a way to get facebook to display the text from posts on the source code? Or is there a better method I should be using to scrape a companies posts.

Code that accepts cookies and logs into facebook:

```
    def login_to_facebook(self):
    sleep_time = 3
    self.browser.get("https://en-gb.facebook.com/")
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    self.browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div._4t2a button[data-cookiebanner='accept_button']").click()
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    username = "email"
    Password = "password"
    email = self.browser.find_element(By.ID, "email")
    email.send_keys(username)
    password = self.browser.find_element(By.ID, "pass")
    password.send_keys(Password)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

Function that given a URL scrolls down the page to get posts to load and returns the HTML source code of the page:

```
    def fetch_unstructured_text_from_facebook(self, url: str) -> str:
    try:

        print(f'Fetching from {url}')
        self.browser.get(url)
        sleep_time = 2
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        start = time.time()
        lastHeight = self.browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        while True:
            self.browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            newHeight = self.browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            if newHeight == lastHeight:
                break
            lastHeight = newHeight
            end = time.time()
            if round(end - start) > 1000:
                break
        time.sleep(15)
        content = self.browser.page_source
        html = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")

    except:
        print("No data crawled")
        html = "No data."

    return html
```

This all works fine, however the output from this function does not actually include the text from posts. Just a bunch of html code, which is fine as long as the text from posts is in there somewhere. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: most likely the content gets loaded with javascript and asynchronous. either way, be aware that scraping is not allowed on facebook, you must use the graph api to get any data of profiles, pages and whatnot.

Comment: @andyrandy Ah ok thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried a hand at Beautiful Soup? It is a Python library that admittedly is archaic right now but it still works in this aspect. You can scour any Facebook profiles for content only if you do have the profile URL and credentials for login into Facebook. You can even scour public profiles sans credentials.

To go through HTML in search of actual text you'd have to configure a script that reads something like this:

```
specific_text = post_bs.find('div', id='div_id').div
    bundled_strings = [p.strings for p in element_carrying_text.find_all('p')]
    all_strings = [repr(string) for group in string_groups for string in group]
raw_data['text'] = all_strings
```